# error pentaho PDI usando spoon con mysql

Tags: pentaho-spoon

realice una conexión exitosa con una base de datos de Mysql pero cuando intento hacer una transformación nueva usando un table_input al hacer click en preview me sale el siguiente error.

> 2018/06/29 15:12:10 - Carte - Installing timer to purge stale objects
>   after 240 minutes. 2018/06/29 15:12:10 - Carte - Installing timer to
>   purge stale objects after 240 minutes. 2018/06/29 20:13:00 -
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.insertupdate.InsertUpdateMeta@23c736ad -
>   ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28-16, build 8.0.0.0-28-16 from 2018-05-17
>   06.25.25 by jenkins) : Unable to get fields from previous steps because of an error 2018/06/30 16:54:09 - /Transformation 1 -
>   Dispatching started for transformation [/Transformation 1] 2018/06/30
>   16:54:09 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28-16, build
>   8.0.0.0-28-16 from 2018-05-17 06.25.25 by jenkins) : Unexpected error 2018/06/30 16:54:09 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28-16,
>   build 8.0.0.0-28-16 from 2018-05-17 06.25.25 by jenkins) :
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:  2018/06/30
>   16:54:09 - Table input.0 - Couldn't get row from result set 2018/06/30
>   16:54:09 - Table input.0 -  2018/06/30 16:54:09 - Table input.0 -
>   Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 18
>   2018/06/30 16:54:09 - Table input.0 - Value '5731766130941153
>   2018/06/30 16:54:09 - Table input.0 - 1523632184 JAZMIN VARGAS
>   2018/06/30 16:54:09 - Table input.0 - 2018-04-1310:10:0710:21:22

Answer (score 0):

Your table input expects a date on column 18 that has the wrong format. Read it as a String and convert it on the next step with the `Metadata tab` of a `Select field` step.

La entrada de su tabla espera una fecha en la columna 18 que tenga el formato incorrecto. Léalo como typo String y conviértalo en el siguiente paso (Step) con la pestaña `Metadatos` de un paso `Seleccionar columnas`. [Google translation]